# atq command problem

Tags: command-line, permissions, cron

I am trying to enable www-data to use the `at` commmand.
First I deleted www-data in `/etc/at.deny` file and tried to execute the following command

```
#sudo -u www-data atq
```

I got this error

```
You do not have permission to use atq.
```

I created the file `/etc/at.allow` and tried the same command again but I got this error

```
Cannot change to /var/spool/cron/atjobs: Permission denied
```

I checked the permissions for /var/spool/cron

```
  drwxrwx--T 2 daemon daemon  4096 شباط  24 17:39 atjobs
```

I cannot figure out what is the problem, please can you help?